# Band 1: Access window out of range in RasterIO()

Tags: gdal, c#, elevation, dted, thinkgeo

I'm trying to implement a mouse_move event handler to display the elevation based on the mouse location. I'm using the ThinkGeo API to display the raster map (.tif) and gdal C# to get the elevation data from Dted file.
Solve issues that for out of range. But after i play around with the map it suddenly throws :

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was Unhandled

with message:

> The input double value is out of range.

What this is means?

**WORKING CODE(EDIT)**

```
  private void Map1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

        {

            Point point = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(Map1);

            ScreenPointF screenPointF = new ScreenPointF((float)point.X, (float)point.Y);
            PointShape pointShape = ExtentHelper.ToWorldCoordinate(Map1.CurrentExtent, screenPointF, (float)Map1.ActualWidth, (float)Map1.ActualHeight);


            string x = pointShape.X.ToString("f6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string y = pointShape.Y.ToString("f6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if(proj4Projection != null)
            {
                //PointShape p = new PointShape(605770.08015, 388756.038425);
                PointShape p2 = proj4Projection.ConvertToExternalProjection(pointShape) as PointShape;


                Gdal.AllRegister(); //Register driver(s).    

                //string Dted = @"C:\N03.dt2";
                double[] gGeoTrans = new double[6];
                Dataset ds = Gdal.Open(@"C:\N03.dt2", Access.GA_ReadOnly); //Open Dataset

                ds.GetGeoTransform(gGeoTrans);
                OSGeo.GDAL.Band gThisBand = ds.GetRasterBand(1);


                double X = Convert.ToDouble(p2.X);

                double Y = Convert.ToDouble(p2.Y);

                // Your query location is X, Y (both doubles), convert your location into
                // local row, col addressing to specify which cell to read
                int row = (int)((gGeoTrans[3] - Y) / -gGeoTrans[5]);// ULY - xcoord / -N-S CellSize;
                int col = (int)((X - gGeoTrans[0]) / gGeoTrans[1]);  // xcoord - ULX / E-W CellSize

                // check here that the row and col are >= 0 and < gDataset.RasterXSize and 
                // gDataset.RasterYSize or you will get a read error.

                // read the value.. reading is done to an array but as we want only one cell
                // it needs to be an array of 1 float.
                float[] buff = new float[1];

                 if ((col <= ds.RasterXSize) && col >= 0)

                 { if ((row <= ds.RasterYSize) && row >= 0)
                    {
                        gThisBand.ReadRaster(col, row, 1, 1, buff, 1, 1, 0, 0); // read the cell value
                     } 
                 } 
                 else 
                 { 
                    return;
                 }

                 float ThisCellValue = buff[0];

                TextBoxSatu.Text = "RSO_WEST(KERTAU)" + "(" + (x) + "," + " " + (y) + ")" + " " + "Long: " + DecimalDegreesHelper.GetDegreesMinutesSecondsStringFromDecimalDegree(p2.X) + " Lat: " + DecimalDegreesHelper.GetDegreesMinutesSecondsStringFromDecimalDegree(p2.Y) + " " + "Height :" +ThisCellValue +"m" ;
```

Comment: You're outside your raster with your row and column, try step debugging and see where you get a value for row and column that is outside the range for your raster (0 to GetXSize(), 0 to GetYSize()). It may be an incorrect projection or a swapping of lat and lon. I'm not versed in the GeoThink API to discern your coordinate transformation.

Comment: I debug it, it like you said it throw error if it out of range. The range for both row and column must be in this range (row =>0 && row=<3601). The 3601 is the value get from ds.rastersize. @MichaelStimson do you know how i can make it not throw error even I out of range? For example if it out of range it will show Height=undefined m. In addtiion, i already change the projection for map same to project of Dted file.

Comment: I didn't include it in the code sample for your other question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305774/using-gdal-in-c-to-read-elevation-at-a-point-from-dted-files but I use a simple if statement if ((col < gDataset.RasterXSize) && col >= 0){ if ((row < gDataset.RasterYSize) && row >= 0){ .. do the work here .. } } else { pForm.PickedValue.Text = "cell is outside raster"; pForm.Update();} to trap when the clicked coordinate is outside the raster; pForm is the associated form and PickedValue is a textbox.

Comment: @MichaelStimson this pForm function is for the Windoform right? Did you know how can i use on WPF?

Comment: Yes pForm is a WinForm and PickedValue is a control on that form with a Text property, but no, I haven't done any WPF development, it's just a propagated message so I guess any mechanism would work - even a messagebox. Have a read of http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-wpf-and-windows-forms/ which might help explain.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thank you for help. I solve the out of range problem, it succes in display the elevation on mouse point. Then after play around with it, it suddenly throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException was Unhandled just like in my question above I edit. Did you know what cause this?

Comment: Run in step debug and watch your variables, if you still can't work it out ask a new question with your updated code and associated error. Argument out of range could mean *any* argument and not just the row and column, it's hard to tell without the updated code.